# Find the next month of a given date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a piece of code to find the next month of the given date.

```
var d = new Date('2018-03-31');
dt = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
```

But i'm wondering what is wrong here since it adds one month to `March` & gives `May` instead of `April`?

**DEMO:**

```js
var d = new Date('2018-03-31');

dt = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: April does not have 31st day :)

Comment: But it `month = month +1` right?

Comment: Yes but `31st April` doesn't exists, so it goes to `1st May`

Comment: It adds a month to the date, not just to the month. So you ends up with April 31 that actually becomes may 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

> **setMonth(month, day)**

`d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, 1);` where day as `1st` day of *next* month

**Only if you are interested in *Month* part**

```js
var d = new Date('2018-03-31');

d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, 1);

dt = new Date(d);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no `31st April` so it goes to `1st May`. You can try it with `2018-03-30`

```js
var d = new Date('2018-03-30');

dt = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1));
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `d = new Date("2018-01-30")`... - And what if TO cannot change the string?

Comment: Then how to get `April`?

Comment: @mpsbhat Check the duplicate

Comment: And also check yogen's answer

Comment: Thank you @ThumChoonTat..!!! Understood the error..!!

Answer (score 0):

setMonth mutates the original Date object - try just `setMonth` and then referencing the date object again, rather than creating a new one:

```js
var d = new Date('2018-03-31');
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: That's still May...

Comment: Er, shows Apr for me. Guess it's a timezone issue

Answer (score -1):

April only has 30 days. If you add 1 to month on the 31st of March, you'll be 1 month later, which is the 1st of May.